# Is there a way to install a certificate with wix with specific group permissions?

Tags: permissions, wix, certificate

I have a certificate in which i need read permissions of a certificate of a very specific group when installing an application.  I am using the wix installer to install the app and certificate but for the life of me, i cannot find a way to provide the correct group.  it needs to be in the local machine store but it seems that when i install the certificate with wix it automatically gives permissions r:w to administrators, msiserver, and system and no rights to owner rights.

I need a 5th group to be defined in there with read permission and must be able to do this on install as manual configuration is out of the question.
is there a way to do this with wix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not easy, but it's doable: [Modifying security on installed certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630247/modifying-security-on-installed-certificates)

Perhaps you should try using a custom action to install the certificate instead of the WiX built-in support. This way maybe it will use the default permissions which work for you.

Comment: I had to write a console application and run that as a custom action during the install...
this seems to be a serious thing to overlook.